# How to use a SymfonyStyle object to get options

Tags: php, symfony, io, console-application

According to:

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-console-style-guide

> ...
>   Using the new style guide in your commands is as easy as instantiating
>   the SymfonyStyle class, passing to it the $input and $output of your
>   command.
>   ... 
>   We recommend you to name this variable $io because you
>   will use it both for input and output operations.
>   ...

A SymfonyStyle instance can be used to handle both input and output operations.

So instead of having an `$input` variable (instance of `InputInterface`) and an `$output` variable (instance of `OutputInterface`), one can just use an $io (instance of `SymfonyStyle`) to handle **both types of operations**.

That is very useful.

But what about the `getOption` of `InputInterface` method used to retrieve the options submitted by the user?

It looks like that `$input->getOption(...)` can't be simply replaced by `$io->getOption(...)` because `SymfonyStyle` does not have that method.

Is there a way to retrieve an user-submitted option simply using an instance of `SymfonyStyle` ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can only catch interactive input with the `SymfonyStyle` Class with the  `askQuestion` method. For the arguments/options passed to the command you need to use the classic way.

Check the usage of the `$input` variable in the source code of the class [here on the repo](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Style/SymfonyStyle.php)

Hope this help